# Auto-size capability of window form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

My window form contains many sub-components including 2 labels. Now I want if 2 these labels are invisible, the window form automatically shrink in order to fit the remaining sub-components. When 2 these labels are visible, the window form automatically grows up in order to contain all components.

I've used the following properties of the window form, but it does not work:

1) `AutoSize = true`

2) `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`

Is it possible for a window form to implement such feature? Otherwise, I have to do it manually??

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is known to work well.  If the label is in a "sub component" (what does that mean?) then the "sub component" has to shrink itself first before the form can shrink.

Answer (score 0):

The window will autosize so that all control fits inside the window. If you make the labels invisible they will still be there and stop the window from getting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

if I got your question right you can achieve this with Multiview...take a Multiview from toolbox and add two view in it (from toolbox) in design mode choose Multiview and in properties panel set the active view index on 0 (by default the value is -1)...put the both of the label in which you willing to hide in one view and let the other stay blank...so now in C# you can switch between the views as you please with a command like MultiView.SetActiveView(View1)...as you can see when you use this method basically there is no label when you switch on the blank view so there is no unnecessary white space in your form